# Обновить определенный кэш в memcache

Tags: php, memcached

У меня на сервере нет MemcacheAdmin, но нужно обновить определенный кэш. Как это сделать?

`memcache->flush()` - сбрасывает весь кэш

**upd**: `memcache->delete('key');` можно, конечно, удалять определенный кэш, и ждать пока он обновится

Answer (score 1):

Установите время жизни записи из приложения.

```
$memcache->set('var_key', 'some really big variable', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 50);
```

https://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php

И да, для очень редко обновляемых данных имеет смысл делать `memcache->delete('key');` это ведь кеш.

Если же вам нужны постоянно эти данные то смотрите в сторону key-value storage